# SQL return multiple columns using max but only one row per user

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I want to do is return all people who have an `enddate <= GETDATE()` but I need to first read the `MAX(enrollmentID)` from the `managementTempTable` table.
Here is what I have so far:

```
select personID, firstName, lastName, [GUID], ouPath 
from managementTable
where personID in 
(
    select personID 
    from 
    (
        select personID 
        from managementTempTable
        where endDate <= GETDATE()
        group by personID
    ) as tbl
) 
and accountEnabled = 1
```

I know this not working because it returns the row of data that has an `endDate <= GETDATE()`. It needs to read the `MAX(enrollmentID)` and then evaluate if the `endDate <= GETDATE()`.

The data in `managementTempTable` looks like:

```
enrollmentID,personID,firstName,lastName,endDate
61490,18213,John,Doe,8/23/2018
64766,18213,John,Doe,NULL
64720,18570,Jane,Doe,10/18/2018
64862,18570,Jane,Doe,NULL
```

The desired result would look like:

```
enrollmentID,personID,firstName,lastName,endDate
64766,18213,John,Doe,NULL
64862,18570,Jane,Doe,NULL
```

Comment: I need the data from the max enrollmentID so 64766 is greater than 61490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `MAX` row by `enrollmentID`  You can try to use subquery in `where`

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM managementTempTable t1
WHERE enrollmentID = (
    SELECT MAX(enrollmentID)
    FROM managementTempTable tt
    WHERE t1.personID = tt.personID
)
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eea006631e1fa711232cb4ec67dac52e)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `row_number()` ? :

```
select mt.*
from (select mt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid order by enrollmentID desc) as seq
      from managementTable mt
      where . . . 
     ) mt
where mt.seq = 1;
```

Comment: I get this error: `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'managementTempTable.enrollmentID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'enrollmentID'.` EnrollmentID is not part of the managementTable, but it is part of managementTempTable.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM managementTempTable 
    WHERE enrollmentID in (
          Select max(enrollmentID) EId
          FROM managementTempTable
          where isnull(enddate,getdate()) <= Getdate()
          group by PersonId)
```